# Stored procedure not working properly in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have been debugging a SQL stored procedure which has to take values (in my code ID and Numb) form table A based on the values (ID) present in the Table C, then square the Numb and store it in Table B i.e. all the things ID, Numb and Square.
I am not able to figure out the problem in the below code

```
 DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE matlab.squaring
     BEGIN
       DECLARE finish BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0; # <- set up initial conditions
       DECLARE square BIGINT(10);
       DECLARE ID INT(10);
       DECLARE Numb INT (10);
       DECLARE id_cur CURSOR FOR
         SELECT ID, Numb FROM A WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT ID FROM c);
         SET @square= @Numb * @Numb

           INSERT INTO B
           (
             ID ,
             Numb ,
             square
           )     values ( ID , Numb, square);


       DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finish = TRUE;
       OPEN id_cur;

     the_loop : LOOP
        FETCH id_cur INTO ID;

        IF finish THEN
           CLOSE id_cur;
           LEAVE the_loop;
        END IF
    END LOOP the_loop;
    END$$
```

When I run the stored procedure the error that pops up is "there seems to be some syntax error in your code, please refer to MYSql guide. "

edit:
one more help please how to execute this stored procedure.

Comment: not sure but in line SET `@square= @Numb * @Numb` there is no semicolon. May be that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various minor errors;

You need a parameter list, even if empty for the procedure;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE matlab.squaring()
```

The continue handler needs to be right below the other declarations;

```
   DECLARE id_cur CURSOR FOR
     SELECT ID, Numb FROM A WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT ID FROM c);
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @finish = TRUE;
```

You forgot a semicolon;

```
SET @square= @Numb * @Numb;
```

You forgot @ on the variable usages;

```
   )     values ( @ID , @Numb, @square);
```

You forgot a semicolon on END IF

```
    END IF;
```

Just as an overview, here's the complete thing updated;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE matlab.squaring()
 BEGIN
   DECLARE finish BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0; # <- set up initial conditions
   DECLARE square BIGINT(10);
   DECLARE ID INT(10);
   DECLARE Numb INT (10);
   DECLARE id_cur CURSOR FOR
     SELECT ID, Numb FROM A WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT ID FROM c);
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @finish = TRUE;
   SET @square= @Numb * @Numb;

   INSERT INTO B
   (
     ID ,
     Numb ,
     square
   )     values ( @ID , @Numb, @square);

 OPEN id_cur;

 the_loop : LOOP
    FETCH id_cur INTO ID;

    IF finish THEN
       CLOSE id_cur;
       LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;
END LOOP the_loop;
END//
```

Answer (score 0):

- You have missed () after PROCEDURE matlab...
- And ; after END IF
- Also, HANDLER declaration should be before any executable code and
  after CURSOR declaration
- Semicolon after SET @square= @Numb * @Numb is needed

So, query should be like this:

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE matlab.squaring ()
 BEGIN
   DECLARE finish BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0; # <- set up initial conditions
   DECLARE square BIGINT(10);
   DECLARE ID INT(10);
   DECLARE Numb INT (10);
   DECLARE id_cur CURSOR FOR
     SELECT ID, Numb FROM A WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT ID FROM c);
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finish = TRUE;
     SET @square= @Numb * @Numb;

       INSERT INTO B
       (
         ID ,
         Numb ,
         square
       )     values ( ID , Numb, square);

   OPEN id_cur;

 the_loop : LOOP
    FETCH id_cur INTO ID;

    IF finish THEN
       CLOSE id_cur;
       LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;
END LOOP the_loop;
END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Missed parameter brackets and semicolon at endif.

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE squaring()
     BEGIN
       DECLARE finish BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0; # <- set up initial conditions
       DECLARE square BIGINT(10);
       DECLARE ID INT(10);
       DECLARE Numb INT (10);
       DECLARE id_cur CURSOR FOR
       SELECT ID, Numb FROM A WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT ID FROM c);
       DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finish = TRUE;
       SET @square= @Numb * @Numb;

           INSERT INTO B
           (
             ID ,
             Numb ,
             square
           )     values ( ID , Numb, square);


       OPEN id_cur;

     the_loop : LOOP
        FETCH id_cur INTO ID;

        IF finish THEN
           CLOSE id_cur;
           LEAVE the_loop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP the_loop;
    END$$
```